# C# values from different table in 1 ComboBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, silverlight

I have a ComboBox set up as followed:

```
private void SiteChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBoxSites.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    Site site = comboBoxSites.SelectedItem.Value as Site;

    comboBoxDetector.Items.Clear();
    if (site != null)
    {
        foreach (Detector detector in site.Detectors)
        {                
                comboBoxDetector.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem()
                {
                    Content = string.Format("{0} ({1})", detector.Track.TrackName, detector.DetectorID),
                    Tag = detector
                });
        }
    }
    if (comboBoxDetector.Items.Count > 0)
        comboBoxDetector.SelectedIndex = 0;

    btnShow_Click(null, null);
}
```

Now this is showing me the correct information in the ComboBox.
However, i want to add 1 extra thing to the content string.

I tried it with adding the query for a start.
After adding the query my code looks like:

```
foreach (Detector detector in site.Detectors)
    {
        LoadOperation<DetectorType> loadOp = context.Load(context.GetEnabledDetectorTypesQuery(detector.DetectorID));

        comboBoxDetector.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem()
        {
            Content = string.Format("{0} ({1})", detector.Track.TrackName, detector.DetectorID),
            Tag = detector
        });
    }
```

Now, i have added the query, and it is not giving any errors.
However, i would like to get results from the query. So i added this code:

```
foreach (Detector detector in site.Detectors)
    {
        LoadOperation<DetectorType> loadOp = context.Load(context.GetEnabledDetectorTypesQuery(detector.DetectorID));
        DetectorType type = loadOp.Entities; //Added this

        comboBoxDetector.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem()
        {
            Content = string.Format("{0} ({1}) {2}", detector.Track.TrackName, detector.DetectorID, type.Description),
            Tag = detector
        });
    }
```

Now Description is the column i want to show. However, `DetectorType type = loadOp.Entities;` is giving an error: `cannot implicitly convert type`

Is there a way so that i can show the `Description` value to the ComboBox?

Comment: This error is clearly saying that you cannot implicitly convert type of **loadOp.Entities** to **DetectorType**. If you're absolutely sure that it's the same type then you can explicitly convert types using **DetectorType type = (DetectorType)loadOp.Entities;**

Comment: @m.rogalski I'm 100% sure because when i put it in a seperate method and call it, it shows me results. Also changing it to what you told gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

loadOp.Entities will be of type `IEnumerable<DetectorType>`. If you are sure that there will only be one entity returned (or you are only interested in the first entity) then you can write `DetectorType type = loadOp.Entities.FirstOrDefault();`